# On button click Visibility of Password in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, visibility

I have used default properties of edittext to make it a "Password" field, `android:password="true"`.

Now, I have a `Button` besides `EditText`. I want as long as I press that button my password characters should visible to me and as I remove my finger from button my password should automatically converts into dots.

I appreciate if can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up an `onTouchListener` on your `EditText`

```
 passwordView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
```

and on `ACTION_DOWN` you do

```
passwordView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

on `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL` you do

```
passwordView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could easily be done with an `OnTouchListener` like this

```
Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button);
yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                //SHOW PASSWORD HERE
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                //HIDE PASSWORD HERE
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be it will helps you

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                      editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return false` as a `default` code path for the `switch`, otherwise the `onTouch()` method will have some code paths that don't return a value